# Spring configuration error WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml FileNotFoundException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, configuration

I have a very simple spring test app. But I get exception even though everything seems to be on order. I might be missing something. Please check the pic to see the project structure and web.xml file contains as well as exception:-

efinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)

[image]

Comment: `WEB-INF` is not a classpath resource but a servlet resource... remove `classpath:` prefix or place your XML files inside `src/main/resources` from where they are copied to `WEB-INF/classes` (which is on classpath).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of resources in a servlet environment:

- *servlet resources* - files uner the root of the web application (loaded via `ServletContext`)
- *classpath resources* - resources on web application's classpath (loaded via `ClassLoader`)

When Spring is supposed to load its configuration it needs to know which mechanism to use.

- **classpath:foo/bar.xml** - will load as classpath resource

  - checking `WEB-INF/classes`, contents of `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` and other shared servlet container's classpath locations
  - when using maven and its project structure, all files from `src/main/resources` will be placed on classpath
- **foo/bar.xml** - will load as servlet resource

  - when using maven and its project structure the `src/main/webapp` folder is the root of your application

---

**TL;DR** As I wrote in the comment, either remove `classpath:` prefix when referencing XML file or move your XML file to `src/main/resources` and remove the `WEB-INF` part.